# Spaces between words become larger in multiline footnotes

Tags: footnotes

My document class is `article`.

If the length of my footnote is rendered as just a one line footnote in my document, then everything works as expected

This is the code in my .tex file -

```
In the above code block\footnote{Full benchmarking code: \url{https://foo.com/bar/hoho.c}} lorem ipsum..
```

This is how it is rendered (correctly) -

[image: working document]

but the spaces in the above line are rendered as multiple spaces in my generated pdf when the footnote extends into the next line

This is the code in my .tex file -

```
In the above code block\footnote{Full benchmarking code: \url{https://foo.com/bar/abcdefhijklmnopqrstu/asadfadfadsasdfafdf//asdfadff/hoho.c}} lorem ipsum..
```

This is how it is rendered (incorrectly - large spaces) -

[image: large spaces]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: could you provide a MWE which reproduces your issue? I tried using only the package `url`and the result is a footnote with a normally spaced text.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue while trying to create an MWE and updated the question with the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following MWE with `xurl` and with `url`. The dummy text from `lipsum` show that your issue comes from the `url` not breaking to achieve the best use of spaces. The package `xurl` corrects this behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xurl} %url
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]} Text.

Text\footnote{Full benchmarking code: \url{https://foo.com/bar/abcdefhijklmnopqrstu/asadfadfadsasdfafdf//asdfadff/hoho.c}} Text.
\end{document}
```

With `url`

[image]

With `xurl`

[image]

Verify [CTAN -- xurl – Allow URL breaks at any alphanumerical character](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xurl) for more info.