# Extra spaces in bibtex entry when reference extends to new line

Tags: spacing, bibtex

I don't care about my bibtex style much, this is what I am using right now -

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{report.bib}
```

The contents of report.bib are -

```
@misc{opencl,
    author = "Khronos Group",
    title = "\textit{The Open Standard for Parallel Programming of Heterogeneous Systems}",
    url = "https://www.khronos.org/opencl/"
}

@misc{thrust,
    author = "NVIDIA",
    title = "\textit{Thrust, the CUDA C++ template library}",
    url = "https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html"
}
```

The primary issue was to try and display the url in the References section. I tried to solve it by appending the url to the title field, but I noticed something strange. When the reference extends to the next line, unnecessary spaces get added to the line -

[image: extra spaces]

But if the reference is aligned to one line -

[image: correct formatting]

the spacing is correct.

I had a [similar issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530251/spaces-between-words-become-larger-in-multiline-footnotes) earlier which was resolved using the xurl package but I am not sure how that might be relevant here.

Comment: Try something like `howpublished = {\url{https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html}},` instead of `url = "https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html"`. `plain` doesn't support a `url` field. Or choose a style that does support URLs (the `natbib` standard styles do as do `urlbst`'s drop-in replacements for the BIbTeX standard styles, so you may want to try `plainurl`). (You'll have to load the `url` or `hyperref` package in order to get good output from `\url`.)

Comment: It has *nothing* to do with the question at hand, but is still something you should fix: `\bibliography{report.bib}` is incorrect. `\bibliography` takes the file name without `.bib` extension. It should be `\bibliography{report}`.